# what is zod equivalent for yup's setLocale?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup, zod

I want to set default custom error messages for zod validation

in yup if I want to have error messages that use i18n I do:

```
import { t } from "i18next";
import * as yup from "yup";
import "./i18next";

yup.setLocale({
  mixed: {
    required: () => t("validation:required"),
  },
  string: {
    min: ({ min }) => t("validation:minStr", { value: min }),
    max: ({ max }) => t("validation:maxStr", { value: max }),
  },
  array: {
    min: ({ min }) => t("validation:minArr", { value: min }),
    max: ({ max }) => t("validation:maxArr", { value: max }),
  },
});
export default yup;
```

how is this possible in zod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`z.setErrorMap(errorMap)`](https://zod.dev/ERROR_HANDLING?id=customizing-errors-with-zoderrormap). The example from the documentation is

```
import { z } from "zod";

const customErrorMap: z.ZodErrorMap = (issue, ctx) => {
  if (issue.code === z.ZodIssueCode.invalid_type) {
    if (issue.expected === "string") {
      return { message: "bad type!" };
    }
  }
  if (issue.code === z.ZodIssueCode.custom) {
    return { message: `less-than-${(issue.params || {}).minimum}` };
  }
  return { message: ctx.defaultError };
};

z.setErrorMap(customErrorMap);
```

For i18n, the [recommended](https://zod.dev/?id=form-integrations) library is [`zod-i18n`](https://github.com/aiji42/zod-i18n) (called `zod-i18n-map` on npm). It has a peer dependency on `i18next`. (example from their README)

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { z } from "zod";
import { zodI18nMap } from "zod-i18n-map";
// Import your language translation files
import translation from "zod-i18n-map/locales/es/zod.json";

// lng and resources key depend on your locale.
i18next.init({
  lng: "es",
  resources: {
    es: { zod: translation },
  },
});
z.setErrorMap(zodI18nMap);

const schema = z.string().email();
// Translated into Spanish (es)
schema.parse("foo"); // => correo inválido
```

Comment: zod code's for`nonempty` method is `too_small` but that's not really accurate, I want the message to be something like "this field cannot be empty" so how is that possible, other than testing for minimum not to be `1`